# I need to get the childnodes of a parent in a list in XML so that I can put them in a loop to put all values in Excel

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing

I am sending one [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) string as a webservices, and I want to interpret it. My XML string is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result is_array="true">
    <item>
        <candidate_offer_id>175</candidate_offer_id><contact_person>Ranjeet Singh</contact_person><offer_status>8</offer_status>
        </item>
        <item><candidate_offer_id>176</candidate_offer_id><contact_person>Ranjeet Singh</contact_person><offer_status>8</offer_status>
    </item>
</result>
```

In this XML string I want to access the child node like candidate_offer_id, offer_status name under node <item> in a list so that later I can run a loop to get all these values in a loop and put it on the Excel sheet. Until now I have written like this:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
var str = XElement.Parse(responseFromServer);
var result = str.Element("item");
```

But how do I interpert the `var` result to get the tag name of parent node <item> in a list and also how to interpret it?

Comment: are the `<code>` tags part your xml?

Comment: Check for OLEDB Adapter , you can write raw xml inside excel.

Comment: Xml declarations cannot be inside the xml.

Comment: no its not part of my xml @Kami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `XmlDocument` class to load and manipulate the XML.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
//doc.Load(responseStream); -- Stream loading
doc.LoadXml(responseFromServer); // where responseFromServer is a xml string

XmlNodeList list = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//item/*");

foreach (XmlNode n in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", n.Name, n.Value);
}

// As a list object that can be converted further
IEnumerable<XmlNode> node = list.Cast<XmlNode>();
```

I am presuming that the `<code>` tags are in error; if not, the xml will need correcting before if can be used.

*** Update : Simplified the code to extract child nodes as list

Comment: @RanjeetSIngh I have further refined the code so that you can extract an `IEnumberable`.  This can be converted to array or used as is, in a loop.

Comment: @RanjeetSIngh use `doc.LoadXml()` instead. `doc.Load()` is attempting to read stream directly, but if that is not working, you can get the string from the stream, and pass that through.

Answer (score 0):

First, your XML is invalid. You want `<code>` after `<?xml>` like:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<code>
    <result is_array=""true"">
        <item>
            <candidate_offer_id>175</candidate_offer_id><contact_person>Ranjeet Singh</contact_person><offer_status>8</offer_status>
        </item>
        <item><candidate_offer_id>176</candidate_offer_id><contact_person>Ranjeet Singh</contact_person><offer_status>8</offer_status>
        </item>
    </result>
</code>
```

I'd make a class to contain each item like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = XElement.Parse(xml);
    var items = str.Descendants("item");

    List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Items.Add(new Item
        {
            OfferID = Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("candidate_offer_id").Value),
            Person = item.Element("contact_person").Value,
            Status = Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("offer_status").Value)
        });
    }
}

class Item
{
    public int OfferID { get; set; }
    public string Person { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to access all these tag name in a array like {'candidate_offer_id', 'offer_status', 'contact person'} so that later i can use that list to give index like item.element(list[0].value) to put my value in excel.

Comment: What i want to get the tag name under <item> node like id,offer_status in a list so that later i can use that in item .element(list[0]). its because if i later send more tags in that xml so still my code should work @jonesy

Comment: oh. you simply want `foreach(var element in items) { Console.WriteLine(element.Name); }`

Comment: but still i have to write as many times as number of tag i have.
I want some one line code if its exists which can give me all the tag name inside node <item> in a list .
i dont know wether it is possible or not.

Comment: then i don't know what you're asking. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) will work for this case since you're not using the entire XML structure.

Assuming your XML is valid such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result is_array="true">
    <item>
        <candidate_offer_id>175</candidate_offer_id>
        <contact_person>Ranjeet Singh</contact_person>
        <offer_status>8</offer_status>
    </item>
    <item>
        <candidate_offer_id>176</candidate_offer_id>
        <contact_person>Ranjeet Singh</contact_person>
        <offer_status>8</offer_status>
    </item>
</result>
```

DTO:

```
public class CandidateOffer
{
    public int CandidateOfferId { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public int OfferStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Parser:

```
public CandidateOffer ParseCandidateOffer(XElement element)
{
    int candidateOfferId;

    if(!int.TryParse(element.Element("candidate_offer_id").Value,
                     out candidateOfferId))
    {
        candidateOfferId = 0;
    }

    var contactPerson = element.Element("contact_person").Value;

    int offerStatus;

    if(!int.TryParse(element.Element("offer_status").Value,
                     out offerStatus))
    {
        offerStatus = 0;
    }

    return new CandidateOffer
            {
                CandidateOfferId = candidateOfferId,
                ContactPerson = contactPerson,
                OfferStatus = offerStatus
            };
}
```

Usage:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var candidateOffers = xDocument.XPathSelectElements("//item")
                               .Select(ParseCandidateOffer);

foreach(var candidateOffer in candidateOffers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(candidateOffer.CandidateOfferId);
}
```